# If cell not highlighted

Tags: vba

I have a VBA sub and inside it I have to do something only for non-highlighted cells. But I don't know how to do it, and I don't find it like this!

```
If Cells(10,10) NOT Highlighted then
```

Can someone tell me how to translate it in VBA?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to check the cells interior color.  Range("A1").Interior.Color

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the cells interior color. Range("A1").Interior.Color

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Range("A1").Interior.Color = 16777215 Then
         Range("A1").Value = "non-highlighted"
    End If

End Sub
```